# Access Module attributes outside the module

Tags: elixir

I have this module in elixir with an attribute:

```
defmodule MyAwesomeModule do
  @awesome_number 7

  # other stuff...
end
```

I'm unable to access `@awesome_number` outside the module. I've tried using the [`Module.get_attribute/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html#get_attribute/2) method, but it throws this error:

```
iex(79)> Module.get_attribute(MyAwesomeModule, :awesome_number)
** (ArgumentError) could not call get_attribute on module MyAwesomeModule because it was already compiled
    (elixir) lib/module.ex:1101: Module.assert_not_compiled!/2
    (elixir) lib/module.ex:1016: Module.get_attribute/3
```

---

So right now, I'm wrapping the module attribute in a method to access it, but it doesn't really make sense to me. I could simply use the method and stop using the attribute all together:

```
defmodule MyAwesomeModule do
  @awesome_number 7

  def awesome_number, do: @awesome_number

  # other stuff...
end
```

So my question is, **is there a better / proper way of doing this?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to access the module attributes outside of the given module. Defining a function to expose the module attribute is the way to go, just what you are already doing.

There still could be a good reason to keep the module attribute, instead of just using the function without the module attribute. It depends on the context. Keep in mind that the value stored in the module attributes is calculated at compilation time. That being said you could have different reasons to **use** or **not to use** the module attribute. Let's look at the following examples:

If the `awesome_number` have to be random generated every time when it's accessed, you have to go just with a function.

If the `awesome_number` needs to be computed (long time) and it doesn't have to change its value, then going with the module attribute + function to expose it, is the way to go.

**Edit:**

There is more to module attributes from what I've said earlier. They perform better than just functions. Here is an example and a quote from the elixir docs:

```
defmodule MyServer do
  @my_data 14
  def first_data, do: @my_data
  @my_data 13
  def second_data, do: @my_data
end

MyServer.first_data #=> 14
MyServer.second_data #=> 13
```

> Notice that reading an attribute inside a function takes a snapshot of
>   its current value. In other words, the value is read at compilation
>   time and not at runtime. As we are going to see, this makes attributes
>   useful to be used as storage during module compilation.

Using them with `Module.register_attribute/3` (https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#register_attribute/3) and especially with the `accumulate: true` option, makes them useful in more ways.

What I want to say is that they can be more useful than just being used as a *constant*.

Comment: Elixir's Plug library is a good example of using the module attributes with `accumulate: true`. Here is a link if you want to dig more in the source https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/19f53a67e672152a7393611681431c1e0ec1be04/lib/plug/builder.ex#L121

Comment: Can u please provide the reference for the following part of the answer? I would like to read more about this :)

`Notice that reading an attribute inside a function takes a snapshot of its current value.`

Comment: Never mind its part of the doc https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html#as-constants

Answer (score 21):

There is a way of "cheating" by using `use` and macros. Look at [this example](http://www.zohaib.me/use-in-elixir-explained/).

For instance suppose you define a module as:

```
defmodule AwesomeLibrary do  
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def print(s), do: IO.puts(s)
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in some module you can use the `use` keyword in this way.

```
defmodule TestLibrary do  
  use AwesomeLibrary
end
```

The effect is that everything defined in the `__using__` block is copied in the new module at compile time. So, in that case, you can use `TestLibrary.print` even if `print` is defined in another module.

This can be used to 'copy constants' too:

```
defmodule AwesomeLibrary do  
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      @awesome_number 7

      def print(s), do: IO.puts(s)
    end
  end
end
```

An example of this that you can look at is [the Timex library](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/getting-started.html). It uses [a dedicated module for constants](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/fcacaffa5ca015e807af87b5d211912bce0587d9/lib/timex/constants.ex) that is imported whenever it is needed.

This seems to me the nicer way to share constants definitions around a big codebase.

Comment: That's a great link in TimeX. This is also how I am using them. I created a concept app to look at the different ways of sharing "constants" across projects: https://github.com/bill-mybiz/elixir-constants-concept . I've also created an SO "Documentation" on constants ("in review" right now), because this is one of the few areas elixir's documentation isn't so strong on. (Just about everything else is documented brilliantly). Another benefit of this method is that you can use them inside of guard statements (since it's compile-time).

Comment: If you just want to use `print/1` in other modules, you can simply `import` the `AwesomeLibrary`, no need for the `use/2` and `__using__/1` macros.